# Version control "in revision" vs. "at revision"

Tags: programming, computing, prepositional-phrases

Should a programmer use *in* or *at* as a preposition when referring to the version-control revision number?

Example: Which is correct, *fixed in revision 12345* or *fixed at revision 12345*?

The [Googlefight result](http://googlefight.com/index.php?word1=in%20revision&word2=at%20revision) is almost equal.

Comment: Do not use GoogleFight for prepositions, it's not meant for that. Semantics! Both prepositions are correct and have subtly different meanings. In general, use ***in***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in revision *n* says that the change occurred in that revision.

> That bug was fixed in revision 23.

Fixed at revision *n* doesn't say when it was fixed, just that we know that revision *n* contains the fix. It could have been fixed earlier. Some people would use the two interchangeably.